# how can i publish paper in open access journal?

Tags: journals, online-publication, open-access

I found a *hybrid journal* that accepts an *open access* option. When I submitted my paper, there was no choice to choose open access and it is submitted now, how can I tell the journal that I need to publish with open access, or will the choice of open access be at then end of the reviewing process?

Comment: You will be offered that choice when the paper is accepted.

Comment: thanks for replying , so it will be at the end of the reviewing process , but excuse me i found that some papers were reviewed and published with in  two months with open access and the other without this option took a long time for reviewing , is there any relation or just luck ?

Comment: There is not enough information to tell. That could easily be a function of luck, how fast the reviewers are, suitability of the original manuscript, time authors take for revisions etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open access is usually (but not always) offered after the peer review process is complete - i.e. after your paper is accepted.

For now there's nothing to do except wait.

Comment: And be prepared to be shocked (shocked, I say) when they tell you the cost of open access.

Comment: @Buffy Shouldn't be *too* shocking at that point; don't most journals make the fees clear at the time of submission?

Comment: @BryanKrause, some users here have been shocked (shocked, I say), so maybe not all.